# Position for 'params.expo_cnt' not found in row; typically this is caused by a mapping inconsistency

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Hadoop/Spark: 2.3.1
ES-Hadoop : 7.0
ES : 7.0

```
spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.config("es.nodes", Configuration.es_video_nodes)
.config("es_port", Configuration.es_port)
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate()
val df = EsSparkSQL.esDF(spark, Configuration.index)
df.show(10)
```

I got the following error:

> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopParsingException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Position for 'params.expo_cnt' not found in row; typically this is caused by a mapping inconsistency
>   at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.readHit(ScrollReader.java:514)
>   at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:292)
>   at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.ScrollReader.read(ScrollReader.java:262)
>   at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.scroll(RestRepository.java:313)
>   at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.ScrollQuery.hasNext(ScrollQuery.java:93)

Description
when read data from es, I got the above error. 
mapping file:

```
"mappings": {
"all": {
"properties": {
"ftime": {
"type": "long"
},
"metadata": {
"properties": {
"fduration": {
"type": "long"
}
}
},
"gvid": {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"ignore_above": 256,
"type": "keyword"
}
}
},
"params": {
"properties": {
"share_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"valid_play_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"expo_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"strict_full_play_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"follow_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"notlike_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"full_play_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"loose_full_play_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"like_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"play_cnt": {
"type": "long"
},
"playtime_sum": {
"type": "long"
}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Hadoop/Spark over ElasticSearch has a problem/bug with fields containing commas(,) or dots(.). In my case the issue was related to new fields I added to the ElasticSearch records after the index was created (update).

The issue dissapeared after renaming the new fields so that they contain no dots (productId instead product.id). By "renaming" I mean I dropped the index and recreated it the right way.